# Copy to clipboard using angular with hyperlink hidden inside text

Tags: html, angular, clipboard, copy-paste

Want to copy something like " <a href="www.google.com"> Google</a> and when I paste this in a markdown editor it should show as [Google](http://www.google.com/) which will be a clickable text.

how to copy a hyperlink to the clipboard in Angular using the latest Clipboard API.

Comment: you should edit your question from suggestion based to more code or error related problem solving other wise you probably suffer with the downvote and eventually your question will be close . read through [dont-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)  and [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . also for clarification from where and how you want to copy, more in specific case will be better approach .

Answer (score 0):

An example method you could use:

```
 copyGoogleLinkMarkupToClipboard(): void {
    const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.value = "<a href='https://www.google.com'>Google</a>";
    document.body.appendChild(textArea);
    textArea.focus();
    textArea.select();
    try {
      document.execCommand('copy');
    } catch (err) {
      alert('unable to write to clipboard');
    }
    document.body.removeChild(textArea);
   
  }
```

for new API, I think it's just:

```
 navigator.clipboard.writeText("<a href='https://www.goole.com'>Google</a>");
```